# Сборочная директория Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет! Поставил локально дженкинс, сделал джобу. Все отрабатывает корректно, но не пойму, в какой директории дженкинс собирает проект?

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По итогу выяснил, что дирректория отображается в логах билда